# Question marked as already solved incorrectly

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Is it possible migrate existing programs installed in windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364504/is-it-possible-migrate-existing-programs-installed-in-windows)
This question is "how to migrate already installed (under Windows) applications to Wine". 
And the question linked as already answered is "how to install applications under Wine". Those are different questions, aren't they?

Comment: Not to me. Many Windows applications will run if the necessary files are present, and this case just devolves to running them under Wine - the linked post. As for other applications, it depends on the app. The general method is what OP gave in their own answer (find reg keys, import them). Ultimately, that too devolves to running Wine.